# Python tkinter GUI is being pushed behind GDM3 polkit password window

Tags: ubuntu, python, gdm, polkit, gdm3

It seems that my [Python PAM RFID solution development](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/662786/running-gui-solution-on-top-of-any-display-manager-login-lock-screen-on-ubuntu-1) has come to an end  and I finally finished developing kind of working GUI solution as well.

### Issue

But, of course I ran into one final issue  - **my GUI is being forced behind all GDM run windows - password window, login and lock screen window**. I've double checked - YES the GUI runs without errors and shows up when needed - BUT it doesn't show on top of windows being run by GDM.

### How it works

1. **Python PAM** module listens for **RFID** card on **NFC** scanner
2. Once card present - it auto-fills user credentials and starts authentication process via remote server
3. Server responds with status codes
4. **Python PAM** module shows `tkinter` window (PIN, Register, Error) according to received state
5. User interacts with form and actions are being done on user behalf in background as well as reply status are being send to remote server.

### Example of an error

Here is a screenshot how it looks on password window (:
[image]

*I made password window little bit more opaque, so you could see that the GUI is there.*

Whatever I do (`ALT`+`TAB`, `TAB` anything that could bring the window up) doesn't work.

The same happens on login/lock screen - only those are not opaque and it seems that they are not working, however, when I enter password and log back in, I see my previously (on login/lock screen) triggered GUI like so:
[image]

### My tries to fix it

- I tried to add these attributes to my `tkinter` root:

  ```py
  tk_root.attributes('-topmost', True)
  tk_root.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', '1')
  ```

  but obviously `gdm3` is being forced on top of everything and this won't simply do the trick.

### Question

**How can I fix this? What would be the best and safest way to force my `tkinter` or any other Python GUI script/app on top of `gdm3` GUIs?**

At this point I'm open to anything - it can be something other than tkinter that will work on top of the GDM3 windows. Out of the box solutions are welcomed as well.

Thank you in advance,

*richardev*